# Will being dismissed affect my DBS check?

Tags: united-kingdom, hiring

I have been dismissed for gross misconduct. (The misconduct was the misuse of vouchers; specifically picking up vouchers/money-off coupons that had been discarded by a customer and using them)

Will that affect my DBS (Disclosure and barring service) check? (Formerly known as a CRB (criminal records bureau) check.)

My disciplinary hearing led straight to dismissal. The police were not involved.

Comment: What are dbs and crb?

Answer (score 5):

**NO**

You mentionned 2 points:

- dismissed
- police not involved

That means there is no *criminal record* of the misuse / misconduct

> Access to the DBS checking service is only available to registered employers who are entitled by law to ask an individual to reveal their **full criminal history** (ref: [Disclosure and Barring Service](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/disclosure-and-barring-service/about))

*The Disclosure and Barring Service (DBS) helps employers make safer recruitment decisions and prevent unsuitable people from working with vulnerable groups, including children. It replaces the Criminal Records Bureau (CRB) and Independent Safeguarding Authority (ISA).*

Unless you have to deal with children or vulnerable group (ref: [Disclosure and Barring Service](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/disclosure-and-barring-service)), or seek for a high-level position related to financial/security matters (ref: [Wikipedia / DBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_and_Barring_Service#Standard_DBS_check)), your previous 'mistake' will not affect DBS as it's not related to this.

As @Dan mentionned it, it's also not about 'employment history or financial status'.

Internal / private disciplinary action **IS NOT** legal action.

Answer (score 3):

No. The DBS check is a Police & Criminal Record check. It doesn't form a "background check" in the sense of checking employment history or financial status etc.