# Will being dismissed from work affect dbs check in England

Tags: united-kingdom, termination, background-check

The offence was sleeping on wake night duty. Work with vulnerable adults. The police was not involved. Disciplinary meeting lead to summary dismissed. 
My other question is will they state it in my reference?
Country is England

Comment: please provide country, so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: What is a "dbs check"?

Comment: Disclosure and barring service in England. Basically security checks before starting employment

Comment: Here's a very similar [Q/A](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/93466/71600), hope this helps

Comment: DBS checks "allows businesses to safeguard their organisation by preventing unsuitable candidates from working with vulnerable people." So probably need legal advice on this (which is out of scope for this site).

Comment: This needs strongly clarifying for other readers - they aren't like security/background checks elsewhere. The DBS check is a specific, government, check which checks against your criminal record. The Enhanced one has slightly more scope in that it lets the Police return things like times you've been accused of a crime (Rightly or wrongly, designed to pick up on people who seem to leave a wake of accusations in their wake even if they can't be proven). As such, the answer provided is correct - if it didn't involve the Police there's no way it can appear on your check.

Answer (score 5):

No, a DBS check is in relation to criminal convictions / cautions / warnings and (in the case of an enhanced DBS check) any other relevant information **held on police records**.

So if you're sure the police were not involved, it can't show up on a DBS check.